# Android subset of OpenGLES 2.0 triangles from VBOs don't show up on one test device vs works as intended on other

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm rendering some super resolution nexrad radar data with a GLSurfaceView. There are 1377156 vertices in my test file. XY with type GL_FLOAT for the position, RGBA with type GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE for the color. 12 bytes total per vertex.

On the new Moto X, everything looks exactly as intended. But on a Nexus 7, it only renders about 3/4 of the triangles in the correct place. There are also some triangles that are showing up where they aren't supposed to.

Nexus 7 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVTji.png

Moto X 2014: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8ts8.png

GLES20.glGetError returns GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR. I have an iOS version sharing approximately the same rendering code and vertex/shader program with the exact same test file that works too (on iPad 2).

Draw code

```
if(renderVertices) {
        int numVertices = 1377156;

        if(loadVertices){
            GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, radarVBO, 0);
            GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, colorVBO, 0);
            myBuffer.position(0);
            GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, radarVBO[0]);
            GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  numVertices*8 , myBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            colorBuffer.position(0);
            GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVBO[0]);
            GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  numVertices*4 , colorBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            loadVertices = false;
        }
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, radarVBO[0]);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, VERTEX_POS_SIZE, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVBO[0]);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(colorHandle, VERTEX_COLOR_SIZE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, true, 0,0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0,numVertices);
}
```

Fragment program

```
varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = colorVarying.rgba;
}
```

Vertex program

```
attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec4 color;

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    colorVarying = color;
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Are you missing _GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray_ calls after both _glVertexAttribPointer_ calls?

Comment: Does it work if you make the draw calls smaller? Instead of making one call for all the triangles, you could try making multiple `glDrawArrays()` calls with smaller batches.

Comment: @harism I had the glEnableVertexAttribArray calls in the onSurfaceCreated before. I tried moving them to the draw call, but that didn't help.

Comment: @reto-koradi I tried batches of 100000 and the result was the same.  Maybe I will try it on a couple more devices and see if any other device has the same problem. I'm starting to think it might be a hardware issue.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the specific device has a problem with the size of the buffer. Probably more a software than a hardware issue. The buffer you're allocating is something over 10 MBytes, which is fairly large, but it's not an absurd amount of memory.

Comment: I tested on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0 and it rendered even less of the view. I am going to try and implement multiple smaller buffers to see if that helps. Do you think there is a way to detect the max size of a VBO during runtime?

Comment: I don't think so. That's the first thing I checked when I saw your question. I thought there might be a queryable limit for the size of a buffer, or the number of vertices in a draw call. But I couldn't find anything like that in the ES 2.0 spec.